# Bootstrap columns contents

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

**Hello** I've created a simple columns using bootstrap but there are problem that if the content of the first column is big the third column will be floated in the right:

```css
#contact-me {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 40px 0;
  /*font-family:Raleway, Arial, 'Open Sans';*/
}

#contact-me .contact-info-nested {
  width: 100%;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  text-align: center;
}

#contact-me .contact-info-nested i {
  display: inline-block;
  margin-bottom: 16px;
  font-size: 50px;
}

#contact-me .contact-info h4 {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 16px;
  line-height: 25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<section id="contact-me">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="contact-info-nested">
          <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
          <h4>Bak-One Company 12345 Hollywood Bvld Street Los Angeles, California</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="contact-info-nested">
          <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
          <h4>+93 345 678 91 23</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="clearfix"> </div>
      <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
        <div class="contact-info-nested">
          <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
          <h4>penciltheme@gmail.com</h4>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

**Note:** please run code snippet in fullscreen

Comment: What exactly you want to do? All in the same row or what?

Comment: what do u want to do with it? The third content should come to the left or on first row?

Comment: I need the third column work well the default behavior that is coming to left not to right !!

Answer (score 0):

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <style>
        #contact-me {
            width: 100%;
            padding: 40px 0;
            /*font-family:Raleway, Arial, 'Open Sans';*/
        }

        #contact-me .contact-info-nested {
            width: 100%;
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            text-align: center;
        }

        #contact-me .contact-info-nested i {
            display: inline-block;
            margin-bottom: 16px;
            font-size: 50px;
        }

        #contact-me .contact-info h4 {
            padding: 5px;
            font-size: 16px;
            line-height: 25px;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>

<section id="contact-me">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="contact-info-nested">
                    <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                    <h4>Bak-One Company 12345 Hollywood Bvld Street Los Angeles, California</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="contact-info-nested">
                    <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                    <h4>+93 345 678 91 23</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <div class="contact-info-nested">
                    <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                    <h4>penciltheme@gmail.com</h4>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use **`col-lg-4`** . Because **`col-lg-6`** use in thee  time and bootstrap column 12 then your last div below line . So i suggest to you can use **`col-lg-4`** three in row then manage all column.

[**Bootstrap Grid**](https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/bootstrap_grid_system.asp)

```css
#contact-me {
 width:100%;
 padding:40px 0;
 /*font-family:Raleway, Arial, 'Open Sans';*/
}
#contact-me .contact-info-nested{
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
#contact-me .contact-info-nested i{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:16px;
    font-size:50px;
}
#contact-me .contact-info h4{
    padding:5px;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="contact-me">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="contact-info-nested">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                        <h4>Bak-One Company 12345 Hollywood Bvld Street Los Angeles, California</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="contact-info-nested">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        <h4>+93 345 678 91 23</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clear"></div>
                <div class="col-lg-4">
                    <div class="contact-info-nested">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                        <h4>penciltheme@gmail.com</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Comment: Thank you but the problem will Appear in the responsive media screen !!

Comment: I tried to use clearfix class but what I need that use clearfix class with col-sm class only

Comment: what is problem in media screen please briefly

Comment: I will update my code to see the more about my problem

Comment: see it please and you understand what I mean

Answer (score 0):

User row when you want to add content in new float you need to use class=row. it will helpfull for this type of issue.

```css
#contact-me {
         width:100%;
         padding:40px 0;
         /*font-family:Raleway, Arial, 'Open Sans';*/
        }
        #contact-me .contact-info-nested{
            width:100%;
            margin-bottom:20px;
            text-align:center;
        }
        #contact-me .contact-info-nested i{
            display:inline-block;
            margin-bottom:16px;
            font-size:50px;
        }
        #contact-me .contact-info h4{
            padding:5px;
            font-size:16px;
            line-height:25px;
        }
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

    <section id="contact-me">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="contact-info-nested">
                            <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                            <h4>Bak-One Company 12345 Hollywood Bvld Street Los Angeles, California</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="contact-info-nested">
                            <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                            <h4>+93 345 678 91 23</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
</div>
 <div class="row">
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div class="col-lg-6">
                        <div class="contact-info-nested">
                            <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                            <h4>penciltheme@gmail.com</h4>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code `<div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>` that this code will clear the float in the small screen:

```css
#contact-me {
 width:100%;
 padding:40px 0;
 /*font-family:Raleway, Arial, 'Open Sans';*/
}
#contact-me .contact-info-nested{
    width:100%;
    margin-bottom:20px;
    text-align:center;
}
#contact-me .contact-info-nested i{
    display:inline-block;
    margin-bottom:16px;
    font-size:50px;
}
#contact-me .contact-info h4{
    padding:5px;
    font-size:16px;
    line-height:25px;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<section id="contact-me">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="contact-info-nested">
                        <i class="fa fa-map-marker"></i>
                        <h4>Bak-One Company 12345 Hollywood Bvld Street Los Angeles, California</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="contact-info-nested">
                        <i class="fa fa-phone"></i>
                        <h4>+93 345 678 91 23</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="clearfix visible-sm"></div>
                <div class="col-md-4 col-sm-6">
                    <div class="contact-info-nested">
                        <i class="fa fa-envelope-o"></i>
                        <h4>penciltheme@gmail.com</h4>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>
```

Answer (score 0):

The bootstrap's grid system is divided in 12, here'w an example:

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
      <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 1</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 1</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 2</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 1</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 2</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 3</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-3">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 1</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 2</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 3</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-3">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 4</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-2">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 1</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 2</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 3</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 4</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 5</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-2">
     <center>
      <h1>Column 6</h1>
     </center>
    </div>
   </div>
   <div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-1">
     <center>
      <h4>Column 1</h4>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
     <center>
      <h4>Column 2</h4>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
     <center>
      <h4>Column 3</h4>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
     <center>
      <h4>Column 4</h4>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
     <center>
      <h4>Column 5</h4>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
     <center>
      <h4>Column 6</h4>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
     <center>
      <h4>Column 7</h4>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
     <center>
      <h4>Column 8</h4>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
     <center>
      <h4>Column 9</h4>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
     <center>
      <h4>Column 10</h4>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
     <center>
      <h4>Column 11</h4>
     </center>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-1">
     <center>
      <h4>Column 12</h4>
     </center>
    </div>
   </div>
```

If you want to make 3 columns, you should use `col-lg-4` in the divs' class instead of 6.